# how to make an external url call in grails

Tags: java, grails

I want to request a payment gateway url from grails app using jquery ajax or on server side in grails app but was not able to request the url from the grails app using jquery ajax request as the request does not get proceed because of the securityfilters.groovy.

Is their any way to filter that particular url in securityFilters.groovy or any way I can request the external url from server side and get the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are running in to Xss issues with making a AJAX call to a different domain. You can instead call a server side action in your application which can call the URL with the necessary parameters. You can use [HTTPBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/HTTP+Builder) library to make calls.

Comment: for using HTTPBuilder do i need to install any plugin ?

Comment: If you are using grails version which is less than 2.0, you  just have to download the library  from the download section and copy it in your lib folder. If you are using 2.0 , you have to define it in the dependencies section. Here is a link to it http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#ivy